# Populating canvas with AJAX response to draw rectangles

Tags: jquery, html, .net, ajax, canvas

Are there any ways to integrate an AJAX response to draw something on a canvas?

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.beginPath();
    context.strokeStyle = 'black';
    context.rect(66, 28, 15, 15);
    context.stroke();
    context.closePath();
```

works perfectly when added in a script block on an aspx page, with the canvas created however I want to generate this data from a DB and create the canvas on the fly.

So far I have managed to create the canvas against a click handler but do not know how to add the values.

```
success: function (msg) {
               DialogMessageBox.Close();
               if (msg.Result == "OK") {
                   var data = eval(msg.Message)
                   $("#ticketArea").html("");
                   var el = document.createElement('canvas');
                   el.height = 550
                   el.width = 850
                   el.style = "border:3px solid orange; border-radius:10px;"
                   $("#ticketArea")[0].appendChild(el);
                   var ctx = el.getContext('2d');
                   ctx.beginPath();
                   ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
                   ctx.scale(1, 1);
             // Insert rest of Msg.Message here????
```

Can I loop through the response? Can it be a simple string such as  "ctx.rect(3, 15, 38, 2); ctx.rect(65, 9, 16, 2); ctx.rect(3, 9, 38, 2);?

Would I be able to make it draw it from that? Or should I put it into a JSON object and loop through?

```
[
{
    "text": "rect(3,15,38,2);"
}
]

 for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                       ctx.data[i].text;
                   }
```

There isn't much info about merging HTML Canvas with AJAX or Server Side calls. Is it even possible?

There's a good post about Canvas Charts - http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Using-HTML5-Canvas-charts-in-ASPNet.aspx but that uses a JS library specifically.

Any help would be appreciated.